# Calculated Fields Looking at Separate Worksheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I'm trying to figure out calculated fields in Pivot Tables in Excel and I haven't really found a clear answer to how to reference another sheet within the calculated field. Basically, my setup has a bunch of data in a Pivot Table which I want to then compare to a bunch of data in a separate worksheet using some kind of sumifs type of formulation. Right now I have a separate table next to the pivot table that pulls in the information from the other sheet but its sloppy and when I filter the Pivot Table it leaves a bunch of unnecessary rows.

Can this be done? I've only really seen calculated field examples referencing stuff within the pivot table itself. My table formula right now is something to the effect of =sumifs('Worksheet'!C:C,'Worksheet'!D:D, "Some Pivot Table Field", 'Worksheet'!E:E, "Some Other Pivot Table Field")